# In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, eigenvalue, hessian-matrix

I am estimating a log-likelihood using `optim()`. I am having some problems with the eigenvalues that don't let me find a valid hessian matrix and, therefore, the standard errors can't be calculated.

Here are the "warning" messages I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) :
  NaNs produced
2: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) :
  NaNs produced
3: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) :
  NaNs produced
4: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) :
  NaNs produced
5: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) :
  NaNs produced
```

Can somebody help me find the problem?

Here's my code:

```
tobit.ll <- function(theta,x,y1,y2,y3)
{
library("copula")
library(mvtnorm)
    p <- nrow(theta)
    n<-nrow(x)
    x<-as.matrix(cbind( 1,x))
    km<- as.numeric(ncol(x))
    beta1 <- theta[1:km]
      beta2 <- theta[(km+1):(2*km)]
    beta3 <- theta[(2*km+1):(km*3)]
        s1  <- theta[(3*km+1)]   ### If sigma^2 is given, take sqrt()
            if (s1 < 0)   return(1e-10)
        s2  <- theta[(3*km+2)]   ### If sigma^2 is given, take sqrt()
            if (s2 < 0)   return(1e-10)
        s3  <- theta[(3*km+3)]  
            if (s3 < 0)   return(1e-10) 
        rho12   <- theta[(3*km+4)] 
            if (rho12< -1 || rho12 > 1)   return(NA)  
        rho13   <- theta[(3*km+5)] 
            if (rho13< -1 || rho13> 1)   return(NA)  
    rho23   <- theta[(3*km+6)]  
            if (rho23< -1 || rho23> 1)   return(NA) 
    fy1 <- ifelse(y1 >0, dnorm(y1,x%*%beta1, s1), (1-pnorm((x%*%beta1)/s1)))
    fy2 <- ifelse(y2 >0, dnorm(y2,x%*%beta2, s2), (1-pnorm((x%*%beta2)/s2)))
    fy3 <- ifelse(y3 >0, dnorm(y3,x%*%beta3, s3), (1-pnorm((x%*%beta3)/s3)))
    Fy1 <- ifelse(y1>0, pnorm((y1-x%*%beta1)/s1),(1-pnorm((x%*%beta1)/s1)))
    Fy2 <- ifelse(y2>0, pnorm((y2-x%*%beta2)/s2),(1-pnorm((x%*%beta2)/s2)))
    Fy3 <- ifelse(y3>0, pnorm((y3-x%*%beta3)/s3),(1-pnorm((x%*%beta3)/s3)))
    norm.cop= ellipCopula("normal", param = c(rho12, rho13, rho23),dim = 3, dispstr = "un")
    u <- as.matrix(cbind(Fy1,Fy2,Fy3))
    dcop<- dCopula(u, norm.cop)
    fy1.lg <- ifelse(fy1==0, log(0.0001), log(fy1))
    fy2.lg <- ifelse(fy2==0, log(0.0001), log(fy2))
    fy3.lg <- ifelse(fy3==0, log(0.0001), log(fy3))
    dcop.lg <- ifelse(dcop==0, log(0.0001), log(dcop)) 
    lglik <- sum(fy1.lg+fy2.lg+fy3.lg) +sum(dcop.lg)
    return(-(lglik))
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters `rho12`, `rho13`, `rho23` are apparently unconstrained:
there is no guarantee that the correlation matrix is positive semi-definite.

You can force it to be positive semi-definite by "truncating" the negative eigenvalues
(but that makes the function you are trying to minimize non-differentiable: 
this can hamper convergence).

```
# Sample data
rho12 <- .9
rho13 <- -.9
rho23 <- .9
correlation <- matrix( c( 1,rho12,rho13, rho12,1,rho23, rho13,rho23,1 ), 3, 3 )

# Fix the correlation matrix
e <- eigen(correlation)
e$values    # Not positive semi-definite
correlation <- e$vectors %*% diag(pmax(0,e$values)) %*% t(e$vectors)
correlation <- cov2cor(correlation)
```

Alternatively, you could parametrize the correlation matrix 
in a different way (e.g., using [angles](http://www.fabiomercurio.it/riskcorr.pdf)).

Comment: if I add this part to my loglikelihood function the rho's wouldn't be parameters but constances, right? I don't seem to understand how to introduce this part in my function.

Comment: Also, if I just need to constraint the correlations, wouldn't change the if to constraint them make the trick?

Comment: The first 4 lines were just a numeric example: you should not include them. If would indeed be easier to return NA if the smallest eigenvalue is negative.

Comment: I tried constraining the rho's in the "if" on the function but gave me singularity problems. I will try your comment and see what happen. Thanks!

Comment: The constraint is not really on the individual correlations,
but on the minimum eigenvalue of the correlation matrix: try
`if( min( eigen( matrix( c( 1,rho12,rho13, rho12,1,rho23, rho13,rho23,1 ), 3, 3 ) )$values ) < 0 ) return(NA)`.

Comment: would that "if" be substituted in place of the if in the individuals correlations?

Comment: Since the fact that the correlations are between -1 and 1 is a consequence of the fact that the eigenvalues are non-negative (and that there are ones on the diagonal), you can actually replace the conditions on the individual correlations. (But they do not do any harm, so you can keep them and add the conditional on the eigenvalues).

Comment: Using your recommendation now give me the error: "Error in optim(par = theta0, fn = tobit.ll, method = "BFGS", x = Xi, y1 = Y1,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite".

Comment: This suggests that the initial values for the correlations do not yield a valid correlation matrix. This can happen, for instance, if the initial values are random.

Comment: Sorry to be asking so maaany questions but how could I overcome this problem? fyi, I didn't choose random number but more as cor(yi,yj). I tried other numbers that should be close based in a similar application with a similar sample and I got the same results.

Comment: What are the values of rho12, rho13, rho23 before the error? (For correlations, you can probably use 0 as initial values.)

Comment: The problem actually was mine, I was taking the wrong initial values. Now taking the right ones, rho12= 0.109,rho13=-0.292 and rho3= -0.419, I got a different error: "Error in optim(par = start, fn = tobit.ll, method = "BFGS", x = Xi, y1 = Y1,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [86]".

Comment: It probably means that the optimizer managed to evaluate the function at the initial point,
but failed to find any nearby point with a finite (non-NA) value -- so it is stuck.
This is likely to happen if the scale of your parameters is very different:
since the correlations are between -1 and 1, the other parameters should be more or less in the same range (10 or 0.1 is fine, but 1e3 or 1e-3 may be too different).
You could try to rescale some of the parameters. Or try other algorithms (`optim`'s `method` argument).

Comment: using other algorithms, e.g. CG, does give me a solution but I still get some negative eigen values.

Comment: I also tried scaling with "BFGS" and it result in some eigenvalues being negative too.